# How do I set up my dual monitors? My config folder does not have monitors.xml in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I tried creating a monitors.xml in config folder using gedit and just saved it there. rebooted but doesn't work.
I am trying this link.
http://www.sudo-juice.com/dual-monitor-settings-in-ubuntu/
But this requires that you should have monitors.xml but I don't have that file on config.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to manually edit configuration files for dual monitor in Ubuntu. Just plug in all monitors you want to use and go to **System Settings** → **Screen Display** to set everything up to your preference.

Comment: So I had one ubuntu in which the monitors.xml file was there and I went to the system settings-> screen display, it couldn't get set. then I changed the monitors.xml and It happened. http://www.sudo-juice.com/dual-monitor-settings-in-ubuntu/ (please see this link), Now I have another ubuntu which doesn't have the monitors.xml in ~/.config folder.

Comment: If there's no monitors.xml file Displays will not detect the external monitor