# Nvidia X Server Settings don't save screen position settings

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have two monitors with resolutions `1366x768`(CRT1) and `1024x768`(CRT0). **CRT0** stays to the right from **CRT1** so common resolution is `(1366+1024)x768`. Recently I noticed that when I move mouse from **CRT1** to **CRT0** it doesn't go to **CRT0** immideately, that is, the common resulution is bigger than `(1366+1024)x768`. I went to `X Server Settings` and there was the following:
[image]
It is really wierd where that `1708` number came from but I didn't think much about it and just changed it to `+1366+0`, saved it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and forgot about it. But on the next boot I see misterious `+1708+0` again. I tried to change settings to this:
[image]
That worked only until reboot too. 
So I am lost. I don't have any errors, I am able to save `xorg.conf` I tried everything I could have thought of, but on each boot I get that `+1708+0`.
[Here's my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](http://pastebin.com/UWDysrzp).

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.19.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-24) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:24:49 UTC 2015

$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-331                                            340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-331
ii  nvidia-340                                            340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96
rc  nvidia-libopencl1-340                                 340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-340                                 340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                          0.6.2                                               amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                       331.20-0ubuntu8                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPD**

The issue with screen position has been fixed, it was about `monitors.xml` file which overrided `xorg.conf` settings, thanks to [@Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm). But when I changed position in `monitors.xml` ubuntu forgot where is my primary monitor and now after reboot I have monitors 'swapped' where I have to move mouse to the left in order to go to right monitor. [Here's my monitors.xml](http://pastebin.com/Kt29BTsG). By the way, [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450767/multi-display-issue-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04) didn't help.

Comment: Could be easily worked around with a small login script or command. The cause is probably your local monitors.xml file or other local source. Anyway, would you care for a workaround? Would need the output of the xrandr command if so. Could you post it somewhere in that case?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes that could be solved with scripts but I'd like to find the cause. If this can't be easily fixed I'll accept the workaround. [Here's xrandr output.](http://pastebin.com/MDzWSL4M)

Comment: Hard to say without sitting behind the computer, but it must be a local source I am pretty sure. Drop me a note if you go for the bad solution :)

Comment: So yes, the guilty was on `monitors.xml` file, thanks! But when I changed position in `monitors.xml` ubuntu forgot where is my primary monitor and now after reboot I have monitors 'swapped' where I have to move mouse to the left in order to go to right monitor... [Here's my monitors.xml](http://pastebin.com/Kt29BTsG). By the way, [This solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450767/multi-display-issue-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04) didn't help.

Comment: Posted the pragmatic solution. Please run the command first, since I am on my tablet, and typos are more likely to happen :). Please let me know if additional settings need to be made. The command can be extended to make any setting you need.

Comment: I found a solution for Ubuntu 19.04 users: https://askubuntu.com/a/1153574/969015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible reasons why a screen configuration does not "survive" a restart. In most cases, there are local sources like the `monitors.xml` file that simply overrule previously made settings.

Finding out what it is exactly, can be time-consuming, so my approach would be the practical solution: simply overrule whatever happens on log in by a simple command or small (`xrandr`) script. In this case, it is probably done by the command:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --pos 0x0 && xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --pos 1366x0
```

which arranges the screens *from left to right*, which you should always do.

#### Add the command to startup (log in)

Choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add, add the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xrandr --output VGA-0 --pos 0x0 && xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --pos 1366x0"
```

Explanation:

- postioning a screen can be done with the command:

  ```
  xrandr --output VGA-0 --pos 0x0
  ```

  to position e.g the left screen, then:
- Always arrange the screens *from left to right*
- The `sleep 15` is to make sure the command runs when the desktop is "ready", and possible local settings do not overrule the command.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it asap

Comment: That helped thanks! The only thing I have added by myself is `xrandr --output VGA-0 --primary` to move Unity Dock to the left monitor. Also there's little typo in `/bin/bash` — it shouldn't have the slash at the end. Anyway I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Timofey Perfect! Glad it works :)

Comment: And another one `xrandr`'s the dust...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

To expound further on one aspect of [@Jacob's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/712858/340383): The monitor.xml file does override any similar left-to-right ordering that is set up in the nVidia Settings.  Under [Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/227669/340383), System Settings/Display updates the `~/.config/monitor.xml` file.  Change the order of what monitor is on the left or right by dragging and dropping the rectangular boxes at the top of the window:

[image]

Start nVidia Settings via the main Search Your Computer button:

[image]

And it is here that you *think* you can change the order, but the `monitor.xml` file will override it:

[image]

I was tempted to just delete the monitors.xml file, in hope that the nVidia Settings would take command of the situation, but [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452493/how-do-i-set-up-my-dual-monitors-my-config-folder-does-not-have-monitors-xml-in#comment599245_452536) on another answer implies this is not a good thing to do.