# Can't drag windows to other monitor

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my Desktop PC (Ryzen 7 + Nvidia GTX 1660Ti). I installed the nvidia-430 driver to get proper graphics. Now my only problem is that I can't drag windows from my main monitor to my second monitor. I can move a part of the window to the second screen, but the last quarter gets stuck on the main monitor and can't pass the border between the screen. To be more precise: The rightmost edge of the window can't move further closer to the left border (to the other screen) than two times the width of the taskbar.

If I go into the NVIDIA X Server Settings and to the "X Server Display Confguration" tab there seems to be a gap between the screens in the layout. Moving the screens together and clicking apply fixes the problem temporarly, but it reoccurs on restart.

Now I'm either looking for a way to fix the underlying problem or alternatevly a way to change the NVIDIA X Server Settings automatically in a way that fixes the problem after booting up the computer.

I have looked up similar problems on here, but the proposed solutions involving sticky edges don't work. Also it doesn't seem like a sticky edges problem, because the mouse isn't near the border when the dragging is stopped.

I have now tried the nvidia-418 driver, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution: The problem is that the screen positions didn't get saved for the next restart. What ultimatly solved my problem was this: [Nvidia X Server Settings don't save screen position settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712825/nvidia-x-server-settings-dont-save-screen-position-settings/712858#712858)

I won't delete the question so that other people with the same question can find the solution.